# React app to replace DOM elements with mySql data

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

I have a very simple React app which replaces DOM elements with data.  My html file looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="appTitle"></div>
        <br />
        <div id="appDescription"></div>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run a basic react app to replace the div id=appTitle and div id=appDescription, the code runs correctly.  The react app looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

let appTitle_literal = "Title Not Found";
let appDescription_literal = "Description Not Found";

const appTitle_element = React.createElement('div', null, appTitle_literal);
const appDescription_element = React.createElement('div', null, 
appDescription_literal);

ReactDOM.render(appTitle_element, document.getElementById('appTitle'));
ReactDOM.render(appDescription_element, document.getElementById('appDescription'));
```

And when I run that code with a npm start command, the browser correctly shows Title not found and Description not found.

The next thing I did was introduce code to connect to a cloud based testing mySql database so now my index.js code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

let appTitle_literal = "Title Not Found";
let appDescription_literal = "Description Not Found";

//
// get the client
const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'rds-mysql-wmcw.cgz0te1dlkah.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    user: 'masterUsername',
    password: 'masterPassword',
    database : 'db_wmcw'
  });

  con.connect((err) => {
  if(err){
      appTitle_literal = "No connection to the server";
      appDescription_literal = err;
  } else {

     //a connection has been established to the database.  Now, run a query against the table 'homepage'
     //to retrieve each row and all columns of the table
     con.query('SELECT * FROM homepage', (err,rows) => {
     //if an error occurs when reading the data from the table, display the error on the console

     if(err) {
        appTitle_literal = "Error reading data from the database";
        appDescription_literal = err;
     } else {
         // a record has been read from the database
         let { appTitle_literal, appDescription_literal } = results[0];
     }
     });       
 }

});
con.end((err) => {
   // The connection is terminated gracefully
   // Ensures all previously enqueued queries are still
   // before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server.
 });

const appTitle_element = React.createElement('div', null, appTitle_literal);
const appDescription_element = React.createElement('div', null, appDescription_literal);

ReactDOM.render(appTitle_element, document.getElementById('appTitle'));
ReactDOM.render(appDescription_element, document.getElementById('appDescription'));
```

As soon as this code is introduced, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in ./~/mysql/lib/Connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 
'c:\jrs\final_project\forth_attempt\React\node_modules\mysql\lib'
 @ ./~/mysql/lib/Connection.js 3:23-37
 @ ./~/mysql/index.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./~/mysql/lib/Connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 
'c:\jrs\final_project\forth_attempt\React\node_modules\mysql\lib'
 @ ./~/mysql/lib/Connection.js 4:23-37
 @ ./~/mysql/index.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./~/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in   'c:\jrs\final_project\forth_attempt\React\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences'
 @ ./~/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js 6:19-32
 @ ./~/mysql/lib/Connection.js
 @ ./~/mysql/index.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js
```

and when I refresh the browser page, the Title not found and Description not found literals no longer appear.

I did some research and found that if I added a node {} to the webpack.config.js file, I could get rid of the error messages so I tried that.  My webpack.config.js file now looks like this:

```
const { resolve } = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),

  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    publicPath: "/"
  },

  context: resolve(__dirname, "src"),

  devtool: "inline-source-maps",

  devServer: {
    contentBase: resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    publicPath: "/",
    historyApiFallback: true
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },

  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    net: 'mock', // not sure if there is a working pollyfill/mock
  }
};
```

I cancelled the currently running instance and reissued the npm start command.  I no longer get the error messages but the Title not Found and the Description not found literals do not appear.

The next thing I did was to back out all the code regarding mqSql and rerun the code just to make sure I could get the literals back, which worked. So I started adding the mySql code back in line by line watching the browser to see when the two literals disappear.  First I added in 
    const mysql = require('mysql');
and the literals remained in the browser.  Then I added in

```
const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'rds-mysql-wmcw.cgz0te1dlkah.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    user: 'masterUsername',
    password: 'masterPassword',
    database : 'db_wmcw'
  });
```

and the literals stayed in the browser.  So, I added this code

```
  con.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        appTitle_literal = "No connection to the server";
        appDescription_literal = err;
     } else {
        appTitle_literal = "made a connection";
        appDescription_literal = "";
     }
    })
```

and the literals disappeared.  I had expected to see made a connection in the browser at this point so I am a little confused.  This is what my index.js file looks like right now:
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

```
let appTitle_literal = "Title Not Found";
let appDescription_literal = "Description Not Found";

//
// get the client
const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'rds-mysql-wmcw.cgz0te1dlkah.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    user: 'masterUsername',
    password: 'masterPassword',
    database : 'db_wmcw'
  });

  con.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        appTitle_literal = "No connection to the server";
        appDescription_literal = err;
     } else {
        appTitle_literal = "made a connection";
        appDescription_literal = "";
     }
    })

const appTitle_element = React.createElement('div', null, appTitle_literal);
const appDescription_element = React.createElement('div', null, appDescription_literal);
```

One additional piece of information, when I open the browser (chrome) development tools and look at the console, I see this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at Connection.connect (Connection.js:90)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap cbc83715470f74f9fced:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:65214)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap cbc83715470f74f9fced:19)
    at module.exports (bootstrap cbc83715470f74f9fced:65)
    at bootstrap cbc83715470f74f9fced:65
connect @ Connection.js:90
(anonymous) @ index.js:18
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap cbc83715470f74f9fced:19
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:65214
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap cbc83715470f74f9fced:19
module.exports @ bootstrap cbc83715470f74f9fced:65
(anonymous) @ bootstrap cbc83715470f74f9fced:65
```

I then added a console.log(con) into the code and I see that the console is stating that con.state is "disconnected".  So this would explain the cannot read error message.  But why is the state disconnected?

Comment: React runs on the browser but `net` (the lib that it can't find) is a node lib so is a serverside library. Check out https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: I'm less concerned with the net not being found than I am in the error message being reported in the browser console.  It appears to me that for some reason, the connection to the mySql database is failing, I think.

Comment: What you are using does not work in the client side.